some fixtures stopped working, breaker not tripped
I have an intermittent issue where a group of electrical items (2 ceiling fans, 2 light fixtures, and 1 exhaust fan) stop working for several hours and after some time they will work again once switches are flipped back on.
All of these things that stop working are on the same breaker as 2 other lights that always work. The breaker does not trip when the group of items mentioned above stop working. There are no GFCIs in this situation. Tripping the breaker and turning it back on has no effect on the problem.
The layout is (I think) like this:
panel-->working light1-->working light2-->non working ceiling fan1-->non working ceiling fan2-->non working light1-->non working light2-->non working exhaust fan
When problem occurs, I still have 120V hot-to-ground at all the switches for the non working items, as well as at the fixtures themselves when switched on.
I have briefly inspected the panel but I did not see any loose neutrals or grounds, scorch marks, or anything obvious to me.
I have pulled the second working light fixture and the first non-working ceiling fan to inspect connections and to see if anything was noticeably wrong. I did not find anything obvious to me.
I have removed face plates and inspected the switches for all the non-working items. Again, I did not find anything obviously wrong.

This sounds like a loose neutral connection, either at "working light 2" or "non working ceiling fan1" or a switch or other connection in between those two locations.
Key is: 120V hot-to-ground
While generally speaking that is a reasonable (and easy, particularly if you don't have neutral in a switch box) thing to test, it only tells you that hot and ground are good but doesn't tell you if neutral is good. The actual functional circuit runs through hot and neutral.
Check each relevant location (last working, first non-working, anything in between) and see if you can find a loose neutral. In addition to screw connections that can include wire nuts. For example, you may have two or more neutral wires connected in the back of a switch box. Testing in that switch box hot to ground (probe to screw on switch and probe to metal box or ground screw) but what you probably need to do is remove the neutral wire nut so you can test to neutral instead of ground. And if you do that and find a loose or otherwise failing connection, there's your answer. If a connection isn't perfect, replace the wire nut - they're very inexpensive.

Thank you so much for your help with this. I removed 'working light2' and 'non working ceiling fan1' again in order to more closely inspect the connections. I wasn't feeling great about the neutral connection in the box for 'working light2'. After re-twisting the wires together and replacing the wire nut, everything seems to be working fine for a couple hours now which is far better than before.
